# Don't see installed add-ons from file

Tags: add-on

I use Preferences -> Add-ons -> Install from zip file. It worked fine with previous versions of the same add-on. Now I mark the zip file, click "Install Add-on from File", and on the bottom see the blue information line telling me that "modules installed () from  into "C:\ ... scripts\addons". Yet I don't see the add-on with its checkbox appear anywhere in Official, Community or Testing. The search option does not find it. Category is "All".

This problem happens with 3 add-ons (two free and one purchased from Blender Market). Yet it does work with two other add-ons, one free and one from Blender Market. The seller from BlenderMarket directed me how to install, doesn't know why it won't, and why it did before. Any ideas?

Blender v2.80.75 On Windows 7 64-bit.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any additional messages printed on the console?

Comment: If I open the console (Shift-F4) and try adding the addon, I don't see any message printed. Is there something else I need to do to see messages? To clarify, the messege "modules installed () from <zip file path> into "C:\ ... scripts\addons" appears at the lowest line of the Blender window (not sure what it is actually called).

Comment: I meant the system console (*Window > Toggle System Console*).

Comment: Thanks. The console window shows just the message above and no further messages.

Comment: Update: I solved this problem with the help of the addon developer. It turned out this addon had a zip file inside a zip file, both named the same, and naturally I was trying to install the wrong one. I'm not sure now what were the problems with some of the other addons I tried and failed to install. I would say current addon installation is not intuitive, at least not for Windows users (is it modeled on some other OS?). Thanks for your patience in this forum.